# How do I copy a folder from remote to local using scp?

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, copy, scp

How do I copy a folder from remote to local host using `scp`?

I use `ssh` to log in to my server.
Then, I would like to copy the remote folder `foo` to local `/home/user/Desktop`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: The OP's question was whether it is possible to copy file from remote to local host **while ssh'd to remote host**. I'm not sure why no single answer has correctly addressed his/her question.

Comment: The premise of the question is incorrect. The idea is, once logged into ssh, how to move files from the logged-in machine back to the client that is logged in. However, scp is not aware of nor can it use the ssh connection. It is making its own connections. So the simple solution is create a new terminal window on the local workstation, and run scp that transfers files from the remote server to local machine. E.g., scp -i key user@remote:/remote-dir/remote-file /local-dir/local-file

Comment: use `mc`: `TAB`, `cd sh://USER@HOST`, use the mc shortcuts, `cd` out when done.

Comment: @sjas: in `mc` it's easier to use **Left/Right** on the menu > **Shell link** where you can type the alias you have in your `~/.ssh/config` e.g. `myhost:` > **OK**

Comment: @jeffmcneill yes your right. But you didn't address directly JeffDror, so I guess most people did not realize that your are answering JeffDror's question.

Answer (score 6164, accepted):

```
scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/
```

By not including the trailing '/' at the end of foo, you will copy the directory itself (including contents), rather than only the contents of the directory.

From `man scp` (See [online manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html))

> -r Recursively copy entire directories

Comment: I google this every time. Related comic: https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: @Gryphius I continue to get a permission denied (publickey) error when using this. How do I resolve that?

Comment: @john-k, many possible reasons (scp not enabled on server, public key not authorized, file permission problem, ...). check if standard ssh works with your key first. consult the existing questions on that topic on sof/serverfault and if that doesn't help, ask a new one on serverfault with debug output from ssh / scp.

Comment: You have to set up the RSA key on both machines - you may have to run `ssh-add` on the local machine as well.

Comment: Two nice-to-knows I found: the `-C` flag adds compression and the `-c` flag lets you pass in other cipher types for better performance, like `scp -c blowfish a@b:something .` [as seen in dimuthu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24256706/741850)

Comment: `scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo/. /home/user/Desktop/foo` always copy and __replace__

Comment: use -p to preserve file modification times, permissions, etc! scp -pr user@...

Comment: This answer lacks important explanation. Will you end up with `Desktop/foo` or will you have `Desktop/allcontentsofFooGohere` scp seems to act weird sometimes to me it does one thing then another

Comment: for example this (typically used in shell scripts): 
`su myuser -c "scp -r /var/www/myapp.org/uploads root@$jcrdevip:/var/www/mydevapp.com/uploads"`
will copy the contents from uploads to uploads. `scp -r /var/www/myapp.org/uploads root@$jcrdevip:/var/www/mydevapp.com/uploads` seems to copy the folder uploads into the `mydevapp.com/uploads` folder creating an unwanted subfolder

Comment: @Toskan with `scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/` you should end up with `Desktop/foo`. 

With `scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo/. /home/user/Desktop/`  you will end up with the contents of `foo` in `Desktop` and all the sub-dirs of `foo` strewn under `Desktop`

Comment: Important to note that you can't be logged into the remote server in the terminal window.  In example if I'm working on my desktop I have to be on local terminal window or it won't work.

Comment: If anyone know the remote server file and he stand in local also using pem file:
scp -i pemfile.pem user@remote-server:~/remote/file/location /local/folder/location

Comment: Does this command merge remote data with local or it will be an entire replace?

Comment: @cptloop The link you posted made me read a trillion comic strips in a day, I didn't get any work done and I completely forgot how I got to that site in the first place. Anyhow, thank you for the link....love the comic strips!

Comment: you'll never need to google it if you use aliases defined in `~/.ssh/config` — then you can do `scp -r mydir myhost:` or `scp -r myhost:thatdir .`

Comment: to copy just content without folder I had to place * scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo/* /home/user/Desktop/

Answer (score 366):

To use full power of **scp** you need to go through next steps:

1. [**Public key authorisation**](https://serverfault.com/questions/2429/how-do-you-setup-ssh-to-authenticate-using-keys-instead-of-a-username-password)
2. [**Create SSH aliases**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412279/how-to-create-alias-for-ssh-command)

Then, for example if you have this **~/.ssh/config**:

```
Host test
    User testuser
    HostName test-site.example
    Port 22022

Host prod
    User produser
    HostName production-site.example
    Port 22022
```

you'll save yourself from password entry and simplify **scp** syntax like this:

```
scp -r prod:/path/foo /home/user/Desktop   # copy to local
scp -r prod:/path/foo test:/tmp            # copy from remote prod to remote test
```

More over, you will be able to use remote path-completion:

```
scp test:/var/log/  # press tab twice
Display all 151 possibilities? (y or n)
```

For enabling remote bash-completion you need to have bash-shell on both `<source>` and `<target>` hosts, and properly working bash-completion. For more information see related questions:

[How to enable autocompletion for remote paths when using scp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/how-to-enable-autocompletion-for-remote-paths-when-using-scp)
[SCP filename tab completion](https://serverfault.com/questions/26768/scp-filename-tab-completion)

Comment: Tab completion is nonsense, just completes from the local host for me.

Comment: @b.long The question is "How to copy remote folder foo to local Desktop". My answer is __"scp -r prod:/path/foo /home/user/Desktop"__. Hope you're able to see relations.

Comment: @Bernhard Remote tab completion is a well know reature. It's nonsense just for you :)

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk Maybe, but your answer does not do that for me, so your answer is at least restricted to some versions at the local and/or host machine.

Comment: @Bernhard For me is was obvious because I'm using bash-shell. Thanks for pointing me on that! Answer updated.

Comment: My mistake @AlexanderYancharuk , I thought you were implying that the OP (@Slasengger) would _need_ to modify his ~/.ssh/config in order to copy folders (which is incorrect). I see now that you were trying give him additional convenience with passwordless ssh.

Comment: @Alexander Yancharuk :  Thanks for the answer, this is more detailed than just covering the syntax alone.

Comment: You can also use a tool like [storm](https://github.com/emre/storm) to *automate* the process of adding servers to ```.ssh/config```

Answer (score 358):

To copy all from **Local Location** to **Remote Location** (Upload)

```
scp -r /path/from/local username@hostname:/path/to/remote
```

To copy all from **Remote Location** to **Local Location** (Download)

```
scp -r username@hostname:/path/from/remote /path/to/local
```

Custom Port where `xxxx` is **custom port** number

```
 scp -r -P xxxx username@hostname:/path/from/remote /path/to/local
```

Copy on current directory from **Remote to Local**

```
scp -r username@hostname:/path/from/remote .
```

**Help:**

1. `-r` Recursively copy all directories and files
2. Always use full location from `/`, Get full location/path by `pwd`
3. `scp` will replace all existing files
4. `hostname` will be hostname or IP address
5. if custom port is needed (besides port 22) use `-P PortNumber`
6. **. (dot)** - it means current working directory, So download/copy from server and paste here only.

**Note:** Sometimes the custom port will not work due to the port not being allowed in the firewall, so make sure that custom port is allowed in the firewall for incoming and outgoing connection

Comment: It seems (at least in recent versions of Raspbian Jessie and Ubuntu) that scp uses -P (uppercase P) for port, while (oddly) ssh uses -p (lowercase).

Comment: -p is reserved for preserving "modification times, access times, and modes from the original file".  So if you're using that for port, it's probably not working ;-)  Unless you have a different version that used the lowercase p differently.

Comment: With ssh, yes.  Not with scp (I assume).

Comment: What should i put if the directory contain a space?

Comment: @hyprfrcb Use `pwd` to get location and use same

Comment: The ˋPortˋˋmight refer to the local? What if both ports are different?

Comment: @Timo There is no matter because you will do scp after SSH login.

Comment: @ShivSingh But if I do remote to local, I do not login.

Comment: As elaborate as this answer is, it's still not clear whether the files of destination will be copied to the other folder destination, or whole folder destination. If you do scp -r .../source .../target then the result will be .../target/source, whereas if you do scp -r .../source/* .../target then .../target will contain the files of source

Answer (score 86):

What I always use is:

```
scp -r username@IP:/path/to/server/source/folder/  .
```

**. (dot)**: it means `current folder`. so copy from server and paste here only.

**IP**: can be an IP address like `125.55.41.311` or it can be host like `ns1.mysite.example`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `.` refers to current directory!

Answer (score 45):

Better to first compress catalog on remote server:

```
tar czfP backup.tar.gz /path/to/catalog
```

Secondly, download from remote:

```
scp user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/backup.tar.gz .
```

At the end, extract the files:

```
tar -xzvf backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: "Better" is highly depends on the data you are transferring and the effort it is to ssh to the server to do zipping/unzipping. And: you can add compression to scp with the `-C` flag, like `scp -C a@b:bigfile .`.

Comment: This reminds me of the comment made by @cptloop ! :D https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: You saved me one extra googling.

Answer (score 24):

Typical scenario,

```
scp -r -P port username@ip:/path-to-folder  .
```

explained with an sample,

`scp -r -P 27000 abc@10.70.12.12:/tmp/hotel_dump .`

where,

```
port = 27000
username = "abc" , remote server username
path-to-folder = tmp/hotel_dump
. = current local directory
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer. -P for a specific SSH port was helpful for me.

Answer (score 23):

And if you have one hell of a files to download from the remote location and if you don't much care about security, try changing the scp default encryption (Triple-DES) to something like 'blowfish'.

This will reduce file copying time drastically.

```
scp -c blowfish -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/
```

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=9107) you get even better performance with `arcfour` in stead of `blowfish`, but it has security flaws.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Files on your unity toolbar

[image]

Press Ctrl + l and write here_goes_your_user_name@192.168.10.123

The 192.168.1.103  is the host that you want to connect.

The here one example

[image]

Comment: Completely off-topic. Downvoted because it contributes to diluting the relevant answers with a suboptimal and excessively specific approach which doesn't even answer the question.

Answer (score 17):

In case you run into *"Too many authentication failures"*, specify the exact SSH key you have added to your severs ssh server:

```
scp -r -i /path/to/local/key user@remote.tld:/path/to/folder /your/local/target/dir
```

Answer (score 15):

The question was how to copy a folder from remote to local with `scp` command.

`$ scp -r userRemote@remoteIp:/path/remoteDir /path/localDir`

But here is the better way for do it with `sftp` - SSH File Transfer Protocol (also Secure File Transfer Protocol, or SFTP) is a network protocol that provides file access, file transfer, and file management over any reliable data stream.(wikipedia).

`$ sftp user_remote@remote_ip`

`sftp> cd /path/to/remoteDir`

`sftp> get -r remoteDir`

`Fetching /path/to/remoteDir to localDir 100%  398  0.4KB/s   00:00`

For help about `sftp` command just type `help` or `?`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why but I was had to use local folder before source server directive . to make it work

```
scp -r . root@888.888.888.888:/usr/share/nginx/www/example.org/
```

Comment: Assuming the user had permissions, could you do an absolute path without using `root@`

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use `rsync` than `scp` - because of ease-of use, while both are available on most Linux platforms

Simple one liner :

```bash
rsync -aP myfiles/ root@10.14.33.129:server_dir/
```

`a` to copy recursively, preserves symbolic links, special and device files, modification times, groups, owners, and permissions. It’s more commonly used than `-r` and is the recommended flag to use.

`P` to show progress

General form :

```bash
rsync -a ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

With `root` as user, and to a specific IP address.

```bash
rsync -aP myfiles/ root@10.14.33.129:server_dir/
```

You can refer to digitalocean [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories) for Rsync

- When inside the folder

`rsync -ap . root@10.14.33.129:server_dir/`

Comment: *"It is better to use rsync than scp"* - You should explain why.

Comment: `rsync -aPI source/ remote:destination/` `-a` for recursive, `-P` for progress, and `-I` for overriding existing files. The command will show to the progress for every file, which is much clearer than `scp`.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the question is incorrect. The idea is, once logged into ssh, how to move files from the logged-in machine back to the client that is logged in. However, scp is not aware of nor can it use the ssh connection. It is making its own connections. So the simple solution is create a new terminal window on the local workstation, and run scp that transfers files from the remote server to local machine. E.g., scp -i key user@remote:/remote-dir/remote-file /local-dir/local-file

Answer (score 0):

For Windows OS, we used this command.

```
pscp -r -P 22 hostname@IP:/path/to/Downloads   ./
```