# How to copy data from remote file to local agent ? (Using Bamboo)

Tags: scp, bamboo

I try to import an existing folder in a "remote server" on my "local agent Bamboo".

I tried to create an **SCP Task** in Bamboo, but it does not work, since the SCP task in Bamboo helps to do the opposite (from local to remote).

I try to create a **Script Task** with Bamboo to import the folder.

I await your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Script Task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html) is right way (or at least working one) to implement "reverse" SCP copy from remote host to Bamboo CI server.

In Script configuration define your [scp command as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304895/993246):

```
/usr/bin/scp -P remote.host.port user@remote.host:/path/to/source_file bamboo.host:/path/to/target_file
```

For correct work don't forget to [setup SSH public key authentication](http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html) for password-less login.

---

Another option is to use custom [bamboo-ssh-plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.edwardawebb.bamboo-ssh-plugin/server/overview) which provides additional **Reverse SCP Task**:

[image: Bamboo Reverse SCP Task]

which can be configured and used completely same way as default SCP Task.

Comment: Unfortunately the bamboo-ssh-plugin is only supports Bamboo versions until 6.8.3 (and has no shared credentials support)