# Not able to get the values of dict keys in ansible yml file into my after.yml file

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

### abc.yml:

```
d_lab: 192.168.1.1
d_location: /ephemeral
ema:
    apple: 10.0.0.1
    orange: 10.0.0.2
    jack: 10.0.0.3
```

### def.yml:

```
- name: Load data
  hosts: CENTRAL_host
  any_errors_fatal: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Copy files from ema
      shell: "scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/abc.pem root@{{ ema['item'] }}:/tmp/ /tmp/test/"
      with_items:
        - "{{ items }}"
```

I am able to access d_lab and d_location, from abc.yml in def.yml.
However when I try to access the value of any keys in the dictionary ema(for eg ema[apple]), I am getting the error

> "
>   TASK [Copy files from ema] *******************************************************************************************************************
>   failed: [<>] (item=apple) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/abc.pem root@10.0.0.1:/tmp/ /tmp/test/", "delta": "0:00:00.089524", "end": "2018-05-10 09:15:24.235767", "failed": true, "item": "apple", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-05-10 09:15:24.146243", "stderr": "Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nscp: /tmp: not a regular file", "stderr_lines": ["Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.", "scp: /tmp: not a regular file"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []} 
>   "

**Please let me know how to access a dictionary inside an ansible playbook.**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the actual error that is happening is:

```
scp: /tmp: not a regular file
```

Which is likely due to `/tmp/` being a directory and not a file on the remote server.

You should be able to recursively copy files by passing the `-r` argument to `scp`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-to-scp-a-folder-from-remote-to-local) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Nathan!
the main issue I faced was fetching the dict values from ansible yml file.
{{ ema[item] }} solved the issue