# scp remote to local permission denied

Tags: ssh, gpu, remote-server, scp

I need to send a pdf file (outputted from a gpu and situated) in a remote server to my local (mac) machine.
I have tried through my local terminal and received errors for each attempt.
the terminal text input and output has been provided below

1.

```
 scp remote:~/path/file.pdf /local/
```

error

```
/local: Permission denied
```

2. 

```
scp -r remote:~/path/file.pdf /local/
```

error

```
/local: Permission denied
```

3. scp -r -P 8888 remote:~/path/file.pdf /local/

error

```
ssh: connect to host remote port 8888: Connection refused
```

Although this question has been posted several times before, I have tried the suggested correct solutions and still have been unable to execute my task.
Any solution or direction in this task will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your local directory should be something `~/foo/bar.pdf`

to download the file in your home, local directory, as bar.pdf

`/` means root mont point and `/local/`  is a directory in root, and you may have no permission to modify it

take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304926/9287628

Comment: after doing that, the file loads up but I cannot find it in the specified directory

Comment: comes up with "foo/bar.pdf : Not a directory "

Comment: do you copy a directory from the remote or just a pdf file?

Comment: pretty much this "scp remote:~/path/bar.pdf ~/local-path"

Comment: I am copying just a pdf file

Comment: tried adding bar.pdf too after /local-path/ aswell

Comment: you have to not include `-r` in your command. are you using that?

Comment: tried it with and without it. doesnt seem to work

Comment: note: i am using an ide terminal (pycharm). Could this be the case?It always works when i transfer from local to remote

Comment: ide is for developing software. just write the command in bash. without `-r`

Comment: just tried it out. tried to open the file from the pdf too using "open bar.pdf". 
But it comes up with "the file /local-path/bar.pdf does not exist".

Comment: what is your operating system? which kind of application are you using to open the pdf?

Comment: the default application is adobe acrobat reader dc

Comment: using macOS mojave version 10.14.6

Comment: can you find the file using `find` ?

Comment: its a kind of weird. if scp hasnt return any error. i supposed it was successful. and your file should be foundable

Comment: so your command is something like `scp user@remote:~/path/file.pdf ~/local/a.pdf` ?

Comment: is it asking for a password from you or its using public key authentication ?

Comment: I tried that but it comes up with "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Comment: this is an issue for all files in my local machine. I tried loading two other files, one other pdf and one pickle. neither of them work