# Download of whole folders of files from ssh

Tags: ssh

I need to select and download many folders stored on a computer that I only have access to with remote ssh connection. I create a list ("list.txt") to download only the folders of my interest, I
tried using a "for" loop with

```
for i  in "list.txt"; do 
    scp -r /pwd/of/folder/of/origen/ /pwd/of/folder/destiny; 
done
```

But don´t read my list and dowload all folders,
also I tried with

```
for i  in "list.txt"; do 
    rsync -Pavizuh /pwd/of/folder/of/origen/$i /pwd/of/folder/destiny; 
done
```

but send mensagge:

```
sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec

total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/d7e177bcf5/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

building file list ... 

rsync: link_stat "/Users/rtorres/daniela/Proyecto/Anotacion/Strain9998" failed: No such file or directory (2)

0 files to consider
```

What can I do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a folder from remote to local using scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-from-remote-to-local-using-scp)

Comment: You're not reading the contents of `lists.txt`, you're using that as the filename to copy.

Comment: You haven't specified the remote server name in either command.

Comment: Not sure why the Python tag, that's not Python syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the contents of "list.txt", not the literal name "list.txt".

```
for i  in $(cat list.txt); do 
    scp -r server:/pwd/of/folder/of/origen/$i /pwd/of/folder/destiny/$i
done
```