# Does SCP command works for non-empty directory, too?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to copy a non-empty directory from a local to remote system?
with `SCP` command or another thing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you just need to add `-r` flag for directories.
You can check scp manual [online scp manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) or you can check this stackoverflow  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-from-remote-to-local-using-scp)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy :)

The command to copy a directory is much like as when copying files. The only difference is that you need to use the -r flag for recursive.

To copy a directory from a local to remote system, use the -r option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1Dv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` flag should solve your problem according to the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).