# Escape space in a username an SCP command

Tags: linux, scp

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-from-remote-to-local-using-scp) shows how to transfer a folder from a remote Windows to a local Linux. In particular, this command:

`scp -r username@hostname:/path/from/remote /path/to/local`

My remote machine is a Windows 11 with a `username` having space like this `nice guy`. This is my attempt:

`scp -r "nice guy"@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:\C:\path\to\folder /home/linux_username/Downloads`

But I get an error:

`nice guy: Invalid username`

How do I escape the space in the Windows `username`?

Comment: That's exactly how you do it, I would say; perhaps there is some weird shit on the Windows side. (There always is - that's why we avoid Windows.)

Comment: This is better asked on superuser.com. You could try `scp -r "nice guy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:/C:/path/to/folder" /home/linux_username/Downloads`. But that's only from rusty memory.